# Get product variation images on Woocommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product-variations

I want to show product variation images (particular image for each variation) on the shop page. I was successfully able to get the name of the variations using the code below (put into "content-product.php"):

```
<?php
$colourvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_colour');
  foreach ( $colourvalues as $colourvalue ) {
   echo $colourvalue->name;
  }
?>
```

Unfortunately there is nothing in the `$colouvalues` array that is the variations image url or anything related to the image.

How can I get product variation images?

Answer (score 11):

You can get a list of the product's variations:

```
// In the product loop:
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

// Outside the product loop:
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
```

Loop over it to get the image from each variation like so:

```
foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
    echo $variation['image_src'];
}
```

Comment: Great! If you aren't already sure that the product is variable you have to check first (with `$product->get_type()` for instance), or the method `get_available_variations()` might not exist.

Answer (score 5):

For Woocommerce 3. loop over like this once you create the variations array.

```
foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
    echo $variation['image']['url'];
}
```

Comment: This grabs the original image - how would you grab the thumbnail? Or any other size for that matter?

Comment: This has been answered by @Elvin85 here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308732/get-url-of-variation-image-thumbnails-in-woocommerce)

Comment: This is only for the thumbnail, for other sizes you can get the attachment id and then use wordpress functions to handle attachments using $variation['image_id']

Answer (score -1):

in functions file

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 5);
function woocommerce_template_single_excerpt() {
            global $product;
            if ($product->product_type == "variable" && (is_shop() )) {
              echo woocommerce_variable_product(); 
            }

 }
```

Comment: The provided code is not related to the question (it does not retrieve the variation image as asked). Moreover there's no built-in function called woocommerce_variable_product() in Woocommerce or WP. As it stands, this looks like a random copy paste from a functions.php file of a custom theme.