# Get URL of variation image thumbnails in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following code to grab the image of every variation for a particular product:

```
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
  echo "<img src=" . $variation['image']['url'] .">";
}
```

This returns the full size image.

**Can anyone tell me how I would modify this to return the 'thumbnail' URL?** (or any other size)

I'm sure it's a fairly simple change but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use thumb_src instead of url.

```
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
  echo "<img src=" . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .">";
}
```

Comment: What if you wanted to only show the variation images? This gets the main parent image as well...

Comment: it can be just because you use same image as parent product image and as some variation image.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the product variation ID, you can do

```
// find out $variation_id, it's different from product_id
$variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
$image_tag = $variation->get_image();

// The below is the whole image tag including <img> and some classes that will help customize it.
echo $image_tag;
```

See related docs found at the Woocommerce reference for [WC_product_variation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_image) class and the [WC_Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) class. The function get_image() is actually inherited from WC_Product, but you can use it in either class.

Answer (score 4):

Since WooCommerce version 3.0.0 you can get the ID of a variation image as:

```
$image_id = $variation->get_image_id();
```

This will return the variation image ID if available, otherwise, the main product image ID will be returned. A variation image could be found in the product back-end as in the image below:

[image]

You can then use this image ID to get the URL to your variation or product thumbnail image as:

```
$image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'thumbnail');
$image_src = $image_array[0];
```

The code snippet is tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

i have different colors and sizes of clothing.
Is it possible to omit the size and only show the thumbnail of a single color

Right now, it is showing thumbnails for color red in small, medium, and large size. Three duplicated thumbnails.

Comment: Please post your questions separately or in the comments(if you are seeking more clarity).