# Make Woocommerce load all variation Images load on page load

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am using **Woocommerce v6.3.1** and **Variation Swatches for WooCommerce v1.1.19** to display all the different variations on my Wordpress website.

I notice it loads a product page at a comfortable speed but the images for a different attribute makes an ajax call and loads the image for that variation at the point of access(ie the swatch button is clicked), which has quite a considerable lag. The image is then cached so the subsequent access of that variation does not have any load time but it's that initial call that I would prefer be loaded on page load.

I am aware that I can make optimizations on the images and I have done so as well. The average size of an image is 500kb at the moment.

Is there any way to make all the images of all variations load on page load? It would be great if those ajax calls are still made asynchronously too!

Comment: you could, for instance, hook `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` (single product display) and load a list of all the product variations images as explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682835/get-product-variation-images-on-woocommerce-shop-page Once you have a list of images urls, you can implement whatever preload strategy you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the variation images in ‘img’ elements. And make the ‘img’ element dissapear by setting ‘display:none’. That way, the browser will start downloading the inages as soon as it encounters the elements and they will be cached for the next time they need to display. You can do this in the product loop:

```
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
    echo '<img src="' . $variation['image_src'] . '" style="display:none;">';
}
```

Outside the loop, you can use this:

```
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product_id );
```